# iOS: Push same view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview

If I have a button and I want to animate the default "UI Page Slide" with the same controller, how would I make that happen when the "nextbutton" is clicked?  I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

```
- (IBAction)NextButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
    NSInteger CurrentQuestionNumber = [QuestionNumber intValue];
    NSInteger NewQuestionNumber = CurrentQuestionNumber + 1;
    QuestionNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", NewQuestionNumber];
    QuestionNumberLabel.text = QuestionNumber;
    QuestionLabel.text = [QuestionsList objectForKey:QuestionNumber];
}
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" about it?  What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: It just cycles through the plist of quesitons...there's no animation between questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of pushing self, you need to instantiate a new instance of the same class, and push that in replace of `self`. You can then get the relevant data and parse it into the interface in your `-viewDidLoad` method.

```
SameClassAsSelf *new_self = [[SameClassAsSelf alloc] init...];
new_self.questionNumber = QuestionNumber;
new_self.questionsList = QuestionsList; //if needed
[self pushViewController:new_self animated:YES];
[new_self release];
```

Comment: It's more efficient that creating a new UIViewController for each question, however, I would recommend just changing the label's text on the page rather than actually pushing a new view controller.

Comment: Good to know. Could you give me some more information? I'm new to objective-c and iOS

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`pushViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController%3aanimated%3a):

> *viewController*
>
> The view controller that is pushed onto the stack. This
>   object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not
>   already be on the navigation stack.

You keep pushing `self` onto the navigation stack. Since it's already on the stack, the navigation controller is likely ignoring the push, and because you are modifying the labels in the view, it just looks like the labels are changing without any animation. (Because that's exactly what's happening.)

Comment: So how do I remedy this? Just animate the labels?

Comment: Pushing same instance on a navigation stack is not allowed but you can create as many instance of a same viewController to push on a single navigationStack.
Read the documentation carefully.