# Swift Make Animation to look like going to new ViewController without having One

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create a small side-feature to display the Files of a Server so a small FileExplorer.

I have one TableViewController (incl. NavigationController) where I diplay all Files of the current Directory.
If I tap on a Folder my intend it to go to the Subfolder and view its Content.

My Problem is that I cant create another TableViewController, because I don't know how much I would need, maybe hundred, because I can't know how many Subfolders are on the Server.

Does anyone know how I can make a kind of Animation so it looks like a new ViewController (incl. Back Button!) and simply reload the TableView with the new Data while animating?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Be specific what you want.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas To make an animation where it looks like your going to the ViewController without having one.

Comment: Why having multiple view controllers is an issue? You should simply use the standard navigation controller. Try a file browser application of any kind and you will see that it uses standard, built-in navigation as well. With iOS and its advanced memory handling, view controller management is not a problem.

Comment: So what do you want to open? open a tableViewController without pushing but inside previous viewController with same animation like push view controller?

Comment: @the4kman I am using an Navigationcontroller as mentioned above, but I'm trying to make a file Explorer so I would need to add unlimited Pages to the Storyboard

Comment: You can push a different instance of the **same** view controller to the stack of a navigation controller and fill it up with different data.

Comment: @the4kman Would be nice if you could explain that a little more

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762445/ios-push-same-view-controller). It's in Objective-C, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user taps on a folder you can simply instantiate a new `DownloadsViewController`, set its properties so that it displays from the selected folder and then push that new instance onto your navigation controller.

Something like:

```
if let newVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "files") as? DownloadViewController {  // The identifier must match the Storyboard ID for the scene in your storyboard
   newVC.rootFolder = selectedFolder // You haven't shown your code, but this will be the folder from the array driving your tableview
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you said "I am using an Navigationcontroller as mentioned above, but I'm trying to make a file Explorer so I would need to add unlimited Pages to the Storyboard".

You don't ned to have unlimited pages in your storyboard. Don't use segues. When you are ready to drill down into another level of your file hierarchy, use `instantiateController(withIdentifier:)` to create a new instance of your view controller, install your data into it, and push it onto your navigation controller.

It makes no sense to create an animation that looks like a view controller push, but isn't really. You **DO** want to push a new instance of your folder contents view controller.

Comment: A unique storyboard identifier for your scene. You should check the docs on that method. They explain it well.

Comment: Your comment makes it clear that you didn't even attempt to research my answer before asking another question. Don't do that.

Comment: I didn't try it out myself bc I'm not home yet but I search in the internet and I didn't find anything regarding Pushing to ITSELF in Swift